# Auto fetch otp kotlin implmentation for sms reading

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, sms, smsmanager

friends,
I am working on `Kotlin` and trying to fetch the received `SMS` in the edit text.I don't know how to implement it. If anybody has the correct `Kotlin` code to fetch `OTP` please post it below however I have just implemented as below and stacked in the implementation so please post below `Kotlin` code if anybody has it

```
class SmsReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {

    private val mListener: SmsListener? = null
    var b: Boolean? = null
    var abcd: String? = null
    var xyz:String? = null

    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        //val bundle = intent!!.getExtras()
        val data = intent!!.extras
        val pdus = data.get("pdus") as Array<Any>


    }
}
```

below is the activity

```
public class OtpActivity extends Activity
{
    EditText ed;
    TextView tv;
    String otp_generated,contactNo,id1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.otp);
        ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.otp_et);
        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.verify_otp);

        SmsReceiver.bin(new SmsListener() {
            @Override
            public void messageReceived(String messageText) {
                ed.setText(messageText);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with RxJava:

```
public static Observable<String> createMessageMonitor(@NonNull final Context context) {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        return fromIntentFilter(context, intentFilter)
                .filter(intent -> intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null)
                .map(intent -> {
                    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                    Object[] pdu_Objects = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    if (pdu_Objects != null) {
                        for (Object aObject : pdu_Objects) {
                            final SmsMessage currentSMS = getIncomingMessage(aObject, bundle);
                            final String senderNumber = currentSMS.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                            final String message = currentSMS.getDisplayMessageBody().trim();
                            Matcher matcher = OTP_PATTERN.matcher(message);
                            if (matcher.matches()) {
                                return matcher.group(1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return "";
                }).filter(message -> !message.isEmpty());

    }
```

Your OTP_PATTERN:

```
private static Pattern OTP_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(\\d{4}) is the OTP for your App.$");
```

Then subscribe the stream:

```
RxBroadcastReceivers2.createMessageMonitor(this)
                .subscribeWith(this,
                        onNext = { /*Your OTP is here*/ },
                        onError = {
                            Timber.e(it, "Registration permission request failed")
                        }
                )
```

**NOTE:** You need to get `Manifest.permission.READ_SMS` before using `createMessageMonitor` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write a receiver, you can use a simple lightweight library https://github.com/VitaliBov/SmsInterceptor

The library has 100% compatibility with Kotlin

You only need to override the interface method, create an Interceptor class and bind it with the life cycle. It looks like this:

```
public class AuthActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMessageListener {
    private SmsInterceptor smsInterceptor;
    private EditText etAuthPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth);
        initViews();
        initSmsInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        smsInterceptor.register();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        smsInterceptor.unregister();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        smsInterceptor.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(String message) {
        // You can perform your validation here
        etAuthPassword.setText(message);
    }

    private void initViews() {
        etAuthPassword = findViewById(R.id.etAuthPassword);
        etAuthPassword.addTextChangedListener(new SmsTextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.length() == 4) {
                    btnAuthPassword.setEnabled(true);
                    checkCode();
                } else {
                    btnAuthPassword.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initSmsInterceptor() {
        smsInterceptor = new SmsInterceptor(this, this);
        // Not necessary
        smsInterceptor.setRegex(SMS_CODE_REGEX);
        smsInterceptor.setPhoneNumber(PHONE_NUMBER);
    }

    private void checkCode() {
        // Validation
        if (isValid) {
            navigateToMainScreen();
        }
    }
}
```